# Join tables when fields aren't equal - PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, join

I created two tables, one stores the questions of a quiz, and the other one stores all the answers, that users made.

The first table called "questions" contains the questions:

```
Field names: id|question
Eg. contents:
1|what's your fav color?
2|what's your fav animal?
```

The second table named "answers" stores all the answers, that users made:

```
Fields names: id|questionid|userid|answer
Eg. contents:
1|1|1|Red
1|1|3|Magenta
1|1|4|Green
```

I'd like to select those questions, that haven't been answered yet by a user.
I store the current user's id in a $_SESSION['id'] session. I tried so many ways, to get these questions, the closest query I've made, was this:

```
$query = SELECT questions.*, answers.* FROM questions LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.id=answers.questionid WHERE answers.id IS NULL OR answers.userid <> '.$_SESSION['id'];
```

This won't work, because if there's another userid in the answers table at the same question id, it still selects that row. What could be the problem? Where did I mess up my query?

Thanks in advance for all of your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user condition is in the wrong place. Since you'll want to try to find a match between the specific user and the question and *detect a non match*, the user part needs to go inside the ON clause with a null check in the WHERE clause;

```
SELECT q.* 
FROM questions q
LEFT JOIN answers a
  ON q.id = a.questionid
  AND a.userid = YOUR_USER_ID
WHERE a.id IS NULL
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/908bc/10).

Comment: With one question answer it works fine, but if there are more questions with more answers this happens :(
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd6560/2
Question 2 had been already answered by userID:1,but the SELECT query still selects the second question.

Comment: @Kobanric Sorry, `a.id` should naturally be `a.questionid` which is the field that should match the question id. Updated the answer/SQLfiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd6560/8

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for Your help.